# how to properly install and configure stubby on a ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, dns, iptables, dhcp

This is what I have done, according to this instructive: [Protect Your DNS Privacy on Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 with DNS over TLS](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-stubby-dns-over-tls), but it does not work in my localnet. **What am I missing**?

Install stubby on ubuntu server (last LTS):

```
sudo apt -y install stubby

sudo systemctl start stubby && sudo systemctl enable stubby && sudo systemctl status stubby
active (running)
```

verifying services:

```
sudo netstat -lnptu | grep stubby
```

[image]

[image]

Editing stubby.yml and adding the IP of the Ubuntu server and adding only a DNS resolution (the rest of the DNS resolutions are commented):

```
sudo nano /etc/stubby/stubby.yml

listen_addresses:
 - 127.0.0.1
 - 0::1

 #CloudFlare DNS over TLS servers
 - address_data: 1.1.1.1
   tls_auth_name: "cloudflare-dns.com"
 - address_data: 1.0.0.1
   tls_auth_name: "cloudflare-dns.com"
```

Restart stubby:

```
 sudo systemctl restart stubby
```

Additional configuration:

a. netplan:

```
 nano /etc/netplan/config.yaml

network:
version: 2
 renderer: NetworkManager
 ethernets:
   enp2s0:
    dhcp4: yes
    dhcp6: no
   enp2s1:
    dhcp4: no
    addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]

 sudo netplan apply      
 sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

b. Internal isc-DHCP-Server (enp2s0 external card internet and enp2s1 internal netcard localnet dhcp):

```
 DNS 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.10
```

**Update:**

Solved!. The configuration is correct. The problem was with my router and not with stubby. You can vote to close the question